# How to apply webkit to each image

Tags: css, html, webkit

This may be a beginner question relating to div ids and classes, but I have applied webkit code to my CSS sheet and want to use the filters on an image to image basis. I am having trouble dividing the filters and they are being applied to all my images. Below is my code:

CSS:

```
img { 
    -webkit-filter: brightness(18%);
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
        transition: all 5s ease;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="img">
<a href="design.html">
  <img src="designwork.png"  width="100%" height="100">
<a href="travel.html">
  <img src="zurich.png" alt="fivera" width="100%" height="50">
<a href="graphics.html">
  <img src="graphics.png" alt="fivera" width="100%" height="50">
<a href="3dmodeling.html">
  <img src="3dmodeling.png" alt="fivera" width="100%" height="50">
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use css classes.  You can add a class or multiple classes to any dom element eg

```
<img>, <div>, <p>
```

etc.  You would do so like this:

```
<img class="filter" src="designwork.png"  width="100%" height="100">
```

then in your CSS you can apply styles to classes using the . identifier.

CSS

```
.filter { 
 -webkit-filter: brightness(18%);
 -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
     -o-transition: all 5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
        transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

Comment: And while this comment will get a lot of people disagreeing, I recommend going through the docs at http://www.w3schools.com/css/ .  They are easy to understand, and will get you started.